# C# DataTable.Select With multiple conditions on a Single Column

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable, datacolumn

I have a DataTable which I want to query one column at a time to check if it meets the set criteria, for some reason the below code gives correct results for the first column after that the results are incorrect.

```
private bool BusinessRulesOne(DataTable dt, DataColumn dc)
{
    bool isSatisfied = false;
    DataRow[] checkColumn = dt.Select(dc.ColumnName + " " + "in (1,2,3,)");

    if (checkColumn.Length != 0)
    {
        isSatisfied = true;
    }
    return isSatisfied;
}
```

On this method Im passing the DataTable I'm querying and DataColumn that I'm currently concentrating on. What needs to happen here is that I want to check if the values on this column consists of the values 1,2 and 3. If yes then return true.

```
private bool BusinessRulesTwo(DataTable dt, DataColumn dc)
{
    bool isSatisfied = false;
    var checkColumn = dt.Select(dc.ColumnName + " " + " = 1");

    if (checkColumn.Count() > 3)
    {
        isSatisfied = true;
    }
    return isSatisfied;
}
```

On the other rule I'm checking if the number of one's (1's) in that column are more than three(3) if yes return true.

Any suggestions are welcome, I'm not clued up with Linq but willing to learn and explore it if it makes life easier.

**Edit With Values in One column**
[image]

Comment: please explain better what issue exactly you have with this code. does it produce incorrect output? do you want to combine two methods in one? do you want to rewrite methods with Linq? I don't see a question mark in the post.

Comment: Sorry for the Unclearity. The code above produces incorrect output, Its suppose to query a DataColumn in a DataTable. On the first rule its suppose to return true if a DataColumn consists of numbers 1,2 and 3. It does that correctly with the first Column. On the second column it returns false instead of true. Hence I'm looking for suggestions, If there is a way in Linq that will be fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first you should know that data table doesn't implement IEnumerable so to use Linq here you should use AsEnumerable:
For the first rule:

```
private bool BusinessRulesOne(DataTable dt, DataColumn dc)   { return dt.AsEnumerable().Any(dataRow => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataRow.Field<string>(dc.ColumnName).First().ToString()) && ( dataRow.Field<int>(dc.ColumnName)  == 1  || dataRow.Field<int>(dc.ColumnName)  == 2 || dataRow.Field<int>(dc.ColumnName)  == 3));}
```

For the second rule:

```
private bool BusinessRulesTwo(DataTable dt, DataColumn dc) { return  dt.AsEnumerable().Where(dataRow => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataRow.Field<string>(dc.ColumnName).First().ToString()) && ( dataRow.Field<int>(dc.ColumnName) == 1)).Count() > 3 ;}
```

Comment: It gives the `'DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable(DataTable)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context` error. Is there a reference that I need to add that I don't know off. I have the `System.Linq`, `System.Data` .

Comment: Tried it its compiling, but on querying it say`Specified cast is not valid.` on `dataRow.Field<int>(dc.ColumnName) == 1`

Comment: @Lord-David Is there any row with non-numeric value in your column ?

Comment: No they are all numeric, some are empty. I think this is where the issue arises.

Comment: Yes I have, `Field` requires that we Cast it. `<int>` wont work in empty fields.

Comment: @Lord-David It should work now. Check the new update.

Comment: Tried the latest update - `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'.`

Comment: @Lord-David Sorry there were a lot of updates. Check it now please.

Comment: Same issue `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'.`

Comment: Your implementation is correct thank you. Only issue was casting which I got help here - [on this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42900511/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-double-to-type-system-string-linq-query/42900793#42900793)

Answer (score 2):

"if the values on this column consists of the values 1,2 and 3, then return true"

`BusinessRulesOne` doesn't express this condition properly. It works differently: "if column contains at least one value from set, then return true". It doesn't guarantee what there are no other values.

here is modified method with inverted logic: "if this column contains smth except 1,2 or 3, then return false"

```
private bool BusinessRulesOne(DataTable dt, DataColumn dc)
{
    DataRow[] checkColumn = dt.Select(dc.ColumnName + " not in (1,2,3)");

    return checkColumn.Length == 0;
}
```

Comment: I checked this it solves the `BusinessRulesOne` method, it seems to be returning correct data. Any idea on the second one?

Comment: @Lord-David, expression looks correct, it should work. can you give an example of DataTable values which produce wrong result?

Comment: See the question edit, thats a column with data. on that I'm saying if 1's are more than three return true. But it doesn't as you can see on that column the 1's are more than three.

Comment: @Lord-David, set a break point on line `if (checkColumn.Count() > 3)` and when it hit, check which rows are in `checkColumn` array.

Comment: I did, its True for the first column after that its False which shouldn't be the case.